# How to plot tree tops and point cloud data in the same window using lidRviewer?

Tags: r, lidr, lidrviewer

I'm following the steps in [The lidRbook Chapter 7.1](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/itd-its.html) to get tree tops. I want to plot the tree tops and point cloud data as illustrated in the book, however, I want to use lidRviewer as it runs much smoother than rgl.

My point cloud dataset is a LAS file and my tree tops are a sf. Is this possible? We can use the example data from the book to test. Please note you need to install both OpenGL and the SDL libraries before installing lidRviewer.

```
#run on the command line 
sudo apt-get install libsdl-dev freeglut3-dev



###in r
library(lidR)
devtools::install_github("Jean-Romain/lidRviewer")

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile, select = "xyzr", filter = "-drop_z_below 0")
chm <- rasterize_canopy(las, 0.5, pitfree(subcircle = 0.2))
plot(las, bg = "white", size = 4)
ttops <- locate_trees(las, lmf(ws = 5))

plot(chm, col = height.colors(50))
plot(sf::st_geometry(ttops), add = TRUE, pch = 3)


#this section is what I want to change to run with lidRviewer
x <- plot(las, bg = "white", size = 4)
add_treetops3d(x, ttops)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm citing the readme of the `lidRviewer` package

> Can only display point clouds. No other feature. This is only a point cloud displayer so not intended as a replacement for rgl.

In short, it is not possible. `rgl` is awesome, and you can guess that a little inactive project like `lidRviewer` won't replace it.